# Variable array in Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm having an issue copying files to a directory in Grunt.

I'm trying to do it dynamically on a particular set of files and also specific static files.

I defined by themes array above

```
var themes = ['default', 'dark', 'everwood', 'heisenberg', 'midnight', 'saddle',
          'slate', 'thebat', 'tronic', 'surgarsmack', 'persimmon', 'seedless',
          'blackturq', 'darkgraygold', 'roma', 'happyhour'
          ]

module.exports....

  build: {
     files: {
      '_build/css/combined-ct-default.css': 'css/src/combined-ct-default.scss',         

      //theme Files
      '_build/css/themes/combined-ct-<%= themes %>.css': 'css/src/combined-ct-<%= themes %>.scss'
     },
     options: {
       sourceMap: false,
       style: 'flatten'
     }
  }
.....
```

The issue I'm running into is that it copies the statically defined file but it isn't copying the other 10 files I have.

Do I need to write an actual task that will loop through the `scss:build` task?

Comment: I believe you would have to loop through it.  I believe what you're using are templates (http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates), and I don't understand what you expect `'...-ct-<%= themes %>.css'` to produce.

Comment: Basically to read through the directory and copy all the files that start with `combine-ct` and their names to the dest directory.  Whether it's by defining what the names are or it will just copy all that start with what I've mentioned